# canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas) does not work inside callback of loadFromJSON function

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

- this question is not duplicated
- this question have nothing to do with ajax

I have developing a SCADA using fabric.js. When I load a serialized canvas from BD, I need to set two variables to false, to work with undo/redo in the canvas. There is an issue, and I don't know if is an unusual problem, or its problem of my code.

My code follows:

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('lienzo', {perPixelTargetFind:true});
//cargaBD is a flag to know when the canvas is loading objects
var cargaBD = true;
//Deshaciendo is a flag to know when i am doing undo/redo
var Deshaciendo = true;
//These vars are used to control object:added event for fabricjs

function finalizarCarga(){ 
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
    cargaBD = false;
    Deshaciendo = false;
}

var json = '{"objects":[{"type":"rect","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":150,"width":150,"height":150,"fill":"#29477F","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"rgba(94, 128, 191, 0.5)","blur":5,"offsetX":10,"offsetY":10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0},{"type":"circle","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":300,"top":400,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"rgb(166,111,213)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":{"color":"#5b238A","blur":20,"offsetX":-20,"offsetY":-10},"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"radius":100}],"background":""}'

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, finalizarCarga); 
console.log(cargaBD);
console.log(DeshaciendoBD);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="lienzo"></canvas>
```

The normal behavior is that a rectangle appears on screen because the function `finalizarCarga` runs when the canvas is loaded from JSON.

But this does not occur. Is it problem of my code, or its problem of fabric.js?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. You don't use the variables `cargaBD` and `Deshaciendo` anywhere in your code. When you add an `alert()` or something to your `finalizarCarga` function, you will see that it runs.

Comment: Ok, the function finalizarCarga runs, but the canvas not render, why?

Comment: Sloved, the issue was that i need to execute the function that canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas) return, with 'code' canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)()